# MySQL: unique field needs to be an index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, field, unique

I have one `UNIQUE` field in my table, and I need to search over it quickly. Do I need to index it?

Do searches over unique fields and indexed fields vary in speed or resource usage?

Comment: read : http://explainextended.com/2009/04/23/making-an-index-unique/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**No**, you dont have to index it again. When you specify `UNIQUE KEY`, the column is indexed. So it has no difference in performance with other indexed column (e.g. PRIMARY KEY) of *same type*.

However if the type is different, there will be little performance difference.

Comment: ok many tks :D . what's difference about performance between Unique key and indexed key during search?

Comment: @Tom There is no difference if both are indexed. Read my answer again.

Comment: So all the columns are indexed if they are under unique key constraint ?

Comment: @Poria Yes. To add a unique constraint the database needs to know if value exists already. To do that it needs to be indexed. Otherwise every insert operation would be very slow.

Answer (score 16):

Every `UNIQUE` field is by definition indexed with a `UNIQUE INDEX` - this also happens to be the fastest searchable access path.

Answer (score 11):

If the field needs to be UNIQUE then it should either be the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

As for performance between `UNIQUE INDEX` and `INDEX`, there is no difference when selecting as both will use the same algorithm i.e. hashing or b-tree.  It's just that with a `UNIQUE` index, especially a numeric i.e. `INT` one, it will be faster than an index which contains duplicates as algorithms such as b-tree are able to more efficiently get to the requested row(s)