# query with exist take so long

Tags: mysql, sql

From my debian terminal I try to execute in mysql client a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_withtime2 AS B  
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_emptytime2 AS A 
WHERE B.trip_id=A.trip_id);
```

`table A` contains around 3 million records. 
`table B` is a sub set of A of around 400000 records.

I'd like to select every records of A thats have a row "parent" with the same id (yes its not an unique/primary id)

Now it takes more than hours...now I'm around 2h and i still seen just a blinking pointer... is it the query correct? Even I can't access to others mysql client like phpmyadmin.
There is any way to speed up the process? 
There is a way to check how many records are processed at running times?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have already indexed `trip_id`? There is another way writing the query, maybe it helps:

```
SELECT *
FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_withtime
WHERE trip_id IN (SELECT trip_id FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_emptytime2)
```

Comment: This should be faster than all the versions with joins, except when the query gets optimized to the same execution plan (which I don't know), then they will be the same.

Comment: trip_id isnt unique... do I need to add a primary key like an autoincrement? the index helps a lot the query?

Comment: @JahStation No, unique is fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393234/mysql-unique-field-need-to-be-index

Comment: Barry and Seblor's answer are exactly the same, but Barry's way is the way it should be written. And left join is not what you want... trust me, I wouldn't say it if I wasn't certain: try this query or look further... @JahStation

Comment: excuse me, but I means that ive not a unique field...so i need to add an unique field to index over this table or i wrong?

Comment: @JahStation yes if it is really unique, you can search stack-overflow on indexing tables or if you have a very specific problem you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a straight JOIN to be much much faster...

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_withtime2 AS B
JOIN stop_times_lazio_set2_emptytime2 AS A ON B.trip_id=A.trip_id
```

Comment: this don't give me the same result as my query, lots of duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simpler request ?

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM stop_times_lazio_set2_emptytime2 AS A, stop_times_lazio_set_withtime2 AS B
WHERE B.trip_id=A.trip_id;
```

With that many records, it will obviously take time.

You can actually prevent it by processing only a few at a time by adding this at the end of the request

```
LIMIT <beginning>, <number of records>
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean, you can make a script that will process some at a time with multiple requests, not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried "left join"??

sample:

```
select columns from withtime 
  left join emptytime on withtime.tripid=emptytime.tripid;
```