# Performance of SELECT Query based on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am having some data in the `session` table, which holds the **user location** along with some other data related to user 
The session table consists of multiple columns like

- **id** - `PRIMARY KEY AUTO-INCREMENT`
- **session_id** - `UNIQUE KEY`(This will be unique for every time, even if user logs in multiple times, this will be generated UNIQUE)
- **user_id** (This user id is unique to every user)
- **user_location** (Holds the coordinates of the user)

**Problem Statment**

I wanted to know that is there any performance difference between the below two queries.
*First Query*

> SELECT `user_location` FROM session WHERE `session_id` = 'some-session-id-goes-here';

*Second Query*

> SELECT `user_location` FROM session WHERE `session_id` = 'some-session-id-goes-here' AND `user_id` ='usome-user-id';

Both the queries give correct data, but is there any effect on performance if suppose there is millions for data present in this session table.

Running both queries on **smaller** set of  `data < 4000` did **not** give any difference in `fetching time`.

Comment: As user-id is not a key and session-id is unique key these 2 query will not have any performance differences. You can also check this using `explain`

Comment: @ruhul okay, I will try this.

Comment: If `session_id` was the primary key (assuming its not null too) rather than a unique key then the performance would be the same and probably better than both queries currently. Is `id` needed?

Comment: ``session_id`` is not **NULL**, it will be some ``UNIQUE`` value every time. Can you tell how can a ``PRIMARY KEY`` would have been better than ``UNIQUE``  in SELECT operation? @danblack   And ``id`` is not much need, just for normal auto-increment

Comment: If `id` referenced in another table, or you code, its probably not needed. An AI does make it easy to insert at the end of a table rather than rebalancing as non-sequential PKs are added. This [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) has a bit on primary vs secondary keys. Basically a secondary key ends implicitly with the primary key id, fetching via a secondary key need to go back to the primary (clustered) key to retrieve fields like `user_location` that isn't in the index. With `session_id` as a PK, its already found. Added insert penalty possibly however.

Comment: Compare the `EXPLAIN {query}` aspects for different table and queries. Should make the forecasted higher volume structures/queries more reliable.

Comment: @danblack thanks for the explanation. I will try with ```EXPLAIN```

Comment: It depends on the index definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you declare a column with `UNIQUE Key` it is indexed by default.
As you have not mentioned if your `user_id` is declared `unique` or not(you said `user_id` is unique, I assume its values are but not defined in your `create table` script). So in that sense they will give same performance. But if you index your `user_id` too then the case can be different.
When you have multiple column indexed and you are querying using them, you must maintain their `index-sequence` after `where` clause and your query performance will be better than the current one. Otherwise, the effect will be negative for not maintaining the sequence order.
You can check columns index sequence by 
`show index from your_table_name`

For some more insight, you can check here [MySQL: unique field needs to be an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393234/mysql-unique-field-needs-to-be-an-index)

Comment: ``user_id`` is not **UNIQUE** in this ``session`` table, but it is **UNIQUE** in some other table called ``users``. I don't think that will matter for this table ``session``.

Comment: you are right, that won't matter  as you have not declared it for this table.

Comment: So in the current scenario, there will be no considerable difference between the two queries I have written. Also by any chance to make this fetching more faster or this is the optimum solution?

Comment: I think so. Right now I can't see any better solution other than indexing the column.